# How to display seats image in android like below picture?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Hi I want to display seat images like this in my app.I am new to android.I don't know what layout and methodology should I use.Currently I am planning list view,but i am not sure what method and layout should i use to use.anybody suggest please
[image]

Comment: use ImageView to show image for 1 seat. Create a layout for 1 row which will contain 4 of this image. Use that layout in ListView or RecyclerView. Prepare different colored versions of seat image to display empty or occupied seats

Comment: you can follow what @Marat, suggested, if you are not getting what he suggested then you have to learn android a bit first

Comment: I would use a GridView. Seems more "natural" to me.

Answer (score 0):

You should use either table layout or linear layout for arranging the seats, and images are used in the button, where the button used is imagebutton. You should insert pictures inside every drawables according to the phone , tablet resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You should start with either [Linearlayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) it display its child view in particular orientation.

```
<Linearlayout orientation="vertical"> 
 <TextView> </TextView>
 <TextView> </TextView>
</Linearlayout>
```

second textview would be displayed below first!

```
<Linearlayout orientation="horizontal"> 
     <TextView> </TextView>
     <TextView> </TextView>
</Linearlayout>
```

second textview would be displayed right first!

There is most used viewGroup is [RelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html), in which views are placed relative to each other! it is used to develop complex design and very powerfull!

Answer (score 0):

Add layout like this dynamically

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        ArrayList<Seat> seats = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < seats.size(); i++) {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);

            if(seats.get(i).getStatus() == AVAILABLE) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.available);
            } else if(seats.get(i).getStatus() == UNAVAILABLE) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.unavailable);
            } else if(seats.get(i).getStatus() == SELECTED) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.selected);
            }
        }

        mylistview.addView(linearLayout);
```

Add the Seat.java

```
public class Seat {
        private int id = 0;
        private String name="";
        private int status=0;

        public int getStatus() {
            return status;
        }

        public void setStatus(int status) {
            this.status = status;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
```